# I have found error in visual studio code in PIL library no module found

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

This PIL library not working and vs code show no module found error while this library already install in this.

Comment: type 'pip list' to see all the packages installed in the environment.

Comment: you might be possibly in different env

Answer (score 0):

The first problem might be that you have installed the packages into another environment.

When you open the terminal and type `python -m pip install [packagename]` you will install the package into the base interpreter which is signified in your `PATH` variable.” (see environment variables).

If you habe activated a virtual environment and then `python -m pip install [packagename]` the specified package will be installed in the current virtual environment that you have activated.

In vscode you need to [attach the virtual environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) to your project.

I also noticed that restarting vscode sometimes also resolves similar problems.